# TableView AllowsMultipleSelection - Still allowing multiple selections

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I posted earlier - on how to stop multiple cells from being able to be selected in my table view - the answer was to use `tableView.AllowsMultipleSelections=false`

I have been trying and failing miserably since, essentially it doesn't seem to be obeying that rule.

My desired output should be one cell is selected and has a green tick next to it (this works) if a new cell is selected, the old tick is removed and moved to the new current cell.

I have tried many approaches and the latest is to create my own index path from the last index selected - then set the accessory view to nil and change selected to false. This also does not work. Please could someone help me with what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks

```
import UIKit

class QuizViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var countries = ["Germany", "France", "England", "Poland", "Spain"];

    var selected = -1;

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false;

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.countries.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        println("indexpath \(indexPath.row)");
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CountryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.countries[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;


        let countryImage = String(self.countries[indexPath.row]) + ".png";
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: countryImage);

        let image: UIImageView = UIImageView();
        cell.accessoryView = image;
        return cell;
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CountryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.countries[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;


        let countryImage = String(self.countries[indexPath.row]) + ".png";
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: countryImage);


        let imageName = "tick.png";
        let image: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName));
        cell.accessoryView = image;

        if(selected != -1){
            //lets remove the tick from the previously selected cell and set selected to false

            var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CountryCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: selected, inSection: 0)) as UITableViewCell

            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.selected = false;
        }

        selected = indexPath.row;
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

**Attempt at proposed solution**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CountryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.countries[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;

    let countryImage = String(self.countries[indexPath.row]) + ".png";
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: countryImage);


    if(cell.selected){
        println("cell was set to selected at \(indexPath.row)");
        let imageName = "tick.png";
        let image: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName));
        cell.accessoryView = image;
    }else{
        println("cell was NOT set to selected at \(indexPath.row)");
        let image: UIImageView = UIImageView();
        cell.accessoryView = image;
    }

    return cell;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {


    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CountryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.selected = true;

    if(selected != -1){
        var previous = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CountryCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: selected, inSection: 0)) as UITableViewCell
        previous.selected = false;
    }
    selected = indexPath.row;
    tableView.reloadData();
}
```

Comment: Did you set the tableview delegate to self?

Comment: i dragged the table view to the view controller yellow button at the top - will add an image to the original post now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't modify the cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  Set the country as "selected" and the previous one as "not selected" and then reload the table data.  Use the selected (or not) state to update the cell visually when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Comment: Hi - thank you for the reply. I have added my attempt at the bottom of the original post, i am still failing miserably :(

Comment: You're still trying to change the cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  What I'm saying is that the backing data needs to know whether it is selected.  So, instead of having a string in `self.countries`, you would have some kind of "Country" object that knows its name and whether it is selected.

Comment: yes this worked - thank you very much, i created an answers object and had an array of type answers - when it does the rebuild of the table it can check the state. Thank you